# Fadetoggle doesn't work at next div

Tags: jquery

I want to fadeToggle when i checked box

```
<div id="single-app">
    <div class="checkbox>">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="check">AAAA</label>
    </div>
    <img src="bbbb" height="140" width="140">
    <div id="app-content">
        <label>Content
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="single-app">
    <div class="checkbox>">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="check">BBB</label>
    </div>
    <img src="bbbb" height="140" width="140">
    <div id="app-content">
        <label>Content
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

and jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#app-content').hide();
    $('#check').click(function(){
        $('#app-content').fadeToggle();
    })
});
```

but it work only first div , next div doesn't have effect from jquery

Comment: Same IDs for multiple DIVs ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using the same ID more than once.


Comment: yes same ids for multiple DIVs because it gen from php foreach

ps. i fixed question to pure html

Comment: @abhitalks - as a matter of fact, i did not.

Comment: @PhawinKhongkhasawan: stop editing the question and start reading the comments

Answer (score 2):

First at all don't use multiple `ID`, id must be unique for each element. You can replace it with `class names`

Then you can set a function like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.app-content').hide();
  $('.single-app').each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $('.check',this).click(function(){
      $this.find('.app-content').fadeToggle();
      })
  })
});
```

Review this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/m7XtE/5/**

Answer (score 0):

Two elements cannot have the same id; two elements *can* have the same class.

Your code should look something like this:

```
<div class="item">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">AAAA</label>

    <img src="bbbb" height="140" width="140">
    <div class="app-content">
        <label>Content<textarea class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea></label>
    </div>
</div>


 <script type="text/javascript">
     //this loops through each item and finds the children
     $(".item").each(function(){
         var $this = $(this);
         var checkbox = $this.children(".checkbox");
         var appContent = $this.children(".app-content").hide();

         checkbox.change(function(){
             appContent.fadeToggle();
         });
     });
 </script>
```